# what is the best method for device location services

Tags: bluetooth, wifi

I am working on a side project at home and need a way to detect when an object is in certain rooms of a house. GPS is not practical because the difference between my living room and bedroom would be too small. I was wondering if bluetooth has measurement capabilities? Or if there is some product that already does this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be intrested in this RFID tracker. Hack-A-Day has a write up on it here:

http://hackaday.com/2010/02/20/rfid-tracking-system/

The project site is:

http://www.ns-tech.co.uk/blog/2010/02/active-rfid-tracking-system/

Simply put rfid tags on what you want to track, hook up a reciever, and connect it to your computer. It's all open source and on a hobyist budget. I'm sure you could modify the code to use the data for whatever server application you want. I heard of jewelry stores using similar devices to know if merchandise is being stolen. Hope I could point you in the right direction.

Comment: This is exactly the kind of thing I was looking for! Hopefully it is easy enough to integrate with a wifi light switch. That'll be a fun programming project. I'll probably end up on stack overflow for that. If I had the rep to vote you up I would! Thanks.

Comment: Do you think that this could be connected to an Arduino? That RFID system uses python coding and connects via serial port, as does Arduino.

Comment: Glad I could help. As for the Arduino question, it would depend on what your planning to do with it. I would need more details on project in order to answer that question. Anyways, good luck and I hope I could help.

Answer (score 0):

You could transmit a coded signal in each room that is not visible in other rooms; IR is a good candidate because it won't penetrate walls and transducers are readily available, cheap, and (in your example) built into phones.  A device can then use the code to identify its location.

There are some challenges, e.g. reflections, open doors allowing leakage, etc, but they should be manageable.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that you want to do this with your smartphone, based off of your comment to user33465. You might want to put this in your original question.

Bluetooth would be a good idea. It has a open range of about 30ft, and much less with obstacles.

Since smartphones can automatically connect to bluetooth devices when they are within range, you will want to have your bluetooth device in each room. So, whenever you enter a new room you connect to a new device. You can have an app running in the background that will send the bluetooth device a packet to trigger your lights to turn on or off.

Sounds like a fun project, good luck!

Answer (score 0):

If your smartphone is Bluetooth Low Energy capable, then you could possibly consider using low cost Bluetooth LE devices distributed around the rooms of your house, in known positions. Then use Trilateration based on RSSI (Received Signal Strength Indication) to estimate the distance to each detected Bluetooth LE device to calculate your position relative to them. I understand, from my similar experiments so far, that such Bluetooth LE capable smartphones can generally connect to upto 4 such devices at once. I have yet to determine the effect of different walls and floors etc on RSSI.